# How to parallelize the Gaussian Elimination algorithm?

Tags: java, c, multithreading, pthreads, gaussian

I was given the task to parallelize this algorithm:

```
public long GEAlgorithmSequential() {
    long begin = System.nanoTime();

    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        double value = matrix[row][row];
        for (int col = row + 1; col < size; col++) {
            matrix[row][col] /= value;
        }

        solutionVector[row] /= value;
        matrix[row][row] = 1.0;

        for (int innerRow = row + 1; innerRow < size; innerRow++) {
            double innerValue = matrix[innerRow][row];
            for (int innerCol = row + 1; innerCol < size; innerCol++) {
                //System.out.printf("matrix[%d][%d] (%.2f) -= %.2f * matrix[%d][%d] (%.2f)\n", innerRow, innerCol, matrix[innerRow][innerCol], innerValue, row, innerCol, matrix[row][innerCol]);
                matrix[innerRow][innerCol] -= innerValue * matrix[row][innerCol];
            }
            solutionVector[innerRow] -= matrix[innerRow][row] * solutionVector[row];
            matrix[innerRow][row] = 0.0;
        }
    }

    //PrintMatrix("Upper Triangular Matrix");

    for (int back = size - 1; back >= 0; back--) {
        answers[back] = solutionVector[back];
        for (int i = back - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            solutionVector[i] -= answers[back] * matrix[i][back];
        }
    }
    return System.nanoTime() - begin;
}
```

I understand this algorithm: The first part takes a row and makes the diagonal 1 by dividing everything else in the row by the diagonal value.

The second part, the two for loops, zero's out everything underneath the diagonal.

The last part, after the PrintMatrix call, we do back substitution and the final answer vector is located in solutionVector.

I was told that this part was parallelizable:

```
for (int innerRow = row + 1; innerRow < size; innerRow++) {
    double innerValue = matrix[innerRow][row];
    for (int innerCol = row + 1; innerCol < size; innerCol++) {
        matrix[innerRow][innerCol] -= innerValue * matrix[row][innerCol];
    }
    solutionVector[innerRow] -= matrix[innerRow][row] * solutionVector[row];
    matrix[innerRow][row] = 0.0;
}
```

To further explain this portion, it is going row by row, performing operations on the entire row (each column, which is the inner loop).

My first thought was to start up a thread for each row, because each row is independent and only relies on the main 'row' we just set to 1, which we don't touch.

So I did this:

```
for (int innerRow = row + 1; innerRow < size; innerRow++) {
    threads[innerRow] = new SubMatrixThread(this, innerRow, row);
    threads[innerRow].start();
}

for (int innerRow = row + 1; innerRow < size; innerRow++) {
    try {
        threads[innerRow].join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The SubMatrixThread is this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    double innerValue = m.GetMatrix()[innerRow][row];
    for (int innerCol = row + 1; innerCol < size; innerCol++) {
        m.GetMatrix()[innerRow][innerCol] -= innerValue * m.GetMatrix()[row][innerCol];
    }
    m.GetSolutionVector()[innerRow] -= m.GetMatrix()[innerRow][row] * m.GetSolutionVector()[row];
    m.GetMatrix()[innerRow][row] = 0.0;
}
```

The m.GetMatrix() and m.GetSolutionVector() are synchronized methods that return the matrix and the vector from the Matrix object.

After doing all of this, the threaded application takes a lot longer than the sequential. For example, on a 512x512 matrix, the sequential algorithm takes 0.039 seconds and the threaded takes > 10 seconds. And the timing just gets worse the bigger the matrix is. IE sequential 4098x4098 takes ~24 seconds and threaded finished in >5 minutes (I just stopped it after that).

For some more information: I first started this program in C, and hit the same problem of threading (from pthreads) taking longer than sequential. My code started getting crazy from me trying to figure this out, so I wrote it in Java to make it easier on myself.

The method I described above starts a thread for each row. I have also only started two threads and split the inner for-loop into two parts instead of n parts. I ran into the same problem there as well.

I have the Java running in IntelliJ on my Windows desktop and I was running the C program on a Linux distro, same problem on both applications.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing that the overhead of creating a Thread and starting it is significant. Use a thread-pool. A simple way to create one (but there are many more ways, look in the Executors class) is

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

You can submit Runnable instances or Callable instances.

If you just want to wait for the calculation to complete, without getting a return value from the calculation, you can use a Runnable:

```
Runnable r = ...;
Future<?> f = threadPool.submit(r);
```

And then later when you want to wait for the result, you call

```
f.get();
```

Where you ignore the return value because a Runnable doesn't have any.

You can also implement `Callable`, return a value at the end of the calculation, and retrieve the value with `f.get()` on the future returned by the `submit` call.

Comment: I tried this method but from what I can tell, the ExecutorService is not meant to be used if you want to wait for the Runnable's to finish. In the algorithm, all of this is happening inside a bigger for-loop, so I need the threads to finish before the next row is started. I looked into the awaitTermination, but the program just hangs. From what I can tell, there is no way "join" equivalent.

Comment: @DevinK I expanded the answer.

Comment: I just implemented your edit and what you suggested, it's still taking just as long though. Any idea why?

Comment: I've implemented, it became faster, but not good enough. https://pastebin.com/Fk3TJVxD . It's 10 times slower for 512, but has the same speed for 4098. It I have to guess, it's some weird cache miss problems, but I don't understand why they would arise.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood the problem is here:

> The m.GetMatrix() and m.GetSolutionVector() are synchronized methods

It means that for every single operation you call synchronization mechanisms, which results into huge performance loss.

Just making them regular methods should be enough. I didn't check the algorithm thoroughly, but you should have no race conditions, because rows are independent.

Not to mention them being synchronized is useless in a different sense: you are not protected from race conditions if there was a risk of them: you get the matrix, but you update its contents after your protection ends (you update the matrix after exiting these methods, so you no longer have a lock).

Comment: I understand what you are saying, that there would be no race conditions since everything is separate. I should have realized that sooner. I did get rid of the synchronized keywords but I didn't see any noticeable difference in timings. I also got rid of the functions altogether and just made the variables for matrix and solutionVector public, but still no noticeable difference.

Comment: @DevinK, Then I think the answer above should work. If it is still not enough, you can handle rows in batches. I.e. if you have K processors, split rows into K groups and process each group by one thread.

Comment: I did mention that I tried the K processors split into K groups idea but still had the same problem where the timing was just absurdly longer than expected.

Comment: @DevinK, sorry, I missed that part.

Comment: No problem, I've just been trying to get this to work for a couple days and have tried a good number of things, nothing seems to work, not really sure why

Answer (score 0):

You are using way too many threads for your needs. Using 512 threads in an application would only make sense if you had a massive CPU / OS infrastructure to support them (as in a supercomputer). In your case, the cost of creating all of these threads heavily outweighs the cost of the computation you are tasking the threads with. Using a thread pool will not help much because this many threads still need to be created -- it's not as if the OS has 512 threads in waiting to be used by any application that launches.

To see a performance benefit in your program, you need to distribute the workload among a reasonable number of threads. For a start, make it match the number of cores you CPU has. That way hopefully you can see it evenly distributed between the cores.